# Cannot implement Java remote interface to communicate with EJB application running on Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, ejb-3.2

I want to expose EJB's running on Websphere Liberty via a remote interface. I have created a test EJB app and a test client. My client seems to connect to Liberty, but the bean is not being created. Below is the error.

```
Mar 14, 2023 7:51:47 AM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 0"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2200)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2221)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:236)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:137)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.is_a(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:229)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._is_a(ObjectImpl.java:130)
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextHelper.narrow(NamingContextHelper.java:69)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:504)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:555)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at work.Main.lookupRemoteBean(Main.java:49)
    at work.Main.testDefaultContextLookupWithCorbanameNameService(Main.java:39)
    at work.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:207)
    ... 14 more
```

I am following samples per:
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/release/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/test-applications/RemoteClientWeb.war/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/client/web/RemoteTxAttrServlet.java

The following is my EJB code.

```
    package test;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    @Stateless(mappedName = "CalcImpl")
    public class CalcImpl implements CalcRemote, CalcLocal {
    
        @Override
        public int add(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }   
    }
```

And the remote interface is as follows.

```
    package test;
    
    import javax.ejb.Remote;
    
    @Remote
    public interface CalcRemote {
        public int add(int a, int b);
    }
```

The stand-alone client app is as follows.

```
    package work;
    
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
    
    import test.CalcRemote;
    
    public class Main {
    
        private static Context defaultContext;
        private static final Integer IIOPPort = new Integer("2809");
        private static final String CorbaName = "corbaname::localhost:" + IIOPPort;
        private static final String CorbaNameNS = CorbaName + "/NameService";
        
        private static final String App = "app1EAR";
        private static final String Module = "app1EJB";
        private static final String CalcBean = "CalcImpl";
    
        private static final String CalcBeanJndi = "ejb/global/" + App + "/" + Module + "/" + CalcBean;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Main m = new Main();
            
            try {
                m.testDefaultContextLookupWithCorbanameNameService();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        
        public void testDefaultContextLookupWithCorbanameNameService() throws Exception {
            
            String jndiName = CorbaNameNS + "#" + CalcBeanJndi + "!" + "test\\.CalcRemote";
            System.out.println("jndiName=" + jndiName);
            CalcRemote bean = lookupRemoteBean(getDefaultContext(), jndiName, CalcRemote.class);
            if (null == bean) {
                System.out.println("Remote bean is null");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("bean.add 1,2 = " + bean.add(1, 2));
        }
        
        public static <T> T lookupRemoteBean(Context context, String jndiName, Class<T> interfaceClass) throws NamingException {
            System.out.println("lookupRemoteBean: JNDI = " + jndiName + ", interface = " + interfaceClass.getName());
            Object remoteObj = context.lookup(jndiName);
            CalcRemote bean = (CalcRemote) remoteObj;
            System.out.println("bean=" + bean.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("lookupRemoteBean: found = " + ((remoteObj == null) ? "null" : remoteObj.getClass().getName()));
            T remoteBean = interfaceClass.cast(PortableRemoteObject.narrow(remoteObj, interfaceClass));
            System.out.println("lookupRemoteBean: returning = " + ((remoteBean == null) ? remoteBean : remoteBean.getClass().getName()));
            return remoteBean;
        }
    
        private static Context getDefaultContext() throws NamingException {
    
            if (defaultContext == null) {
                defaultContext = new InitialContext();
            }
            return defaultContext;
        }
            
    }
```

The variable jndiName per the above resolves as follows.

corbaname::localhost:2809/NameService#ejb/global/app1EAR/app1EJB/CalcImpl!test.CalcRemote

It seems to be that I am close to getting things working, but not quite there yet. Is there something that I have not setup on Liberty? Why the error 'COMM_FAILURE' and 'port: 0'?

I'm really stuck.  Have found similar problems elsewhere on stackoverflow, but no resolutions that help me.  Help appreciated.
Thanks

**Update.**
Discovered that all works fine via the following examples. Just need to make sure all lines up correctly.
[Remote EJB examples](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/release/dev/com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.remote_fat/test-applications/RemoteClientWeb.war/src/com/ibm/ws/ejbcontainer/remote/client/web/RemoteTxAttrServlet.java)

Comment: REF `WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 Feature Pack for EJB 3.0` https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247611.html?Open , Download `PDF`, and Open `Additional materials`, download example code `7611code.zip`, you can find example code. Make sure, you have a WebSphere App Server.

Comment: Have you checked that nothing else is running on the NameService port?